# Elementary OS Run script at login

Tags: x11, login, elementary-os

I have an old Thinkpad T400 and currently running Elementary OS. Since two finger scrolling does not work out of the box I have to run a command whenever I want it to be enabled. I found the command [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186895/how-to-enable-two-finger-scrolling-on-lenovo-thinkpad-t400-w540#186952).

I thought it would work if I put the few lines into .profile or .bashrc. But it doesn't. So now I run it by adding it to the startup as a custom command.(System Setting -> applications -> Startup) This does work.

When I log out and back in it still works but when the laptop goes into standby and wakes up again, the two finger scrolling does not work anymore.

I want to run these few lines of script every time I log in and at boot.
So far It works at boot.

How do I run this script every time I log in?

Comment: It would help if you explicitly asked (as in a sentence with a question mark) what you want to know. Now suggestion can range from what kind of new laptop to buy to what to do to prevent the T400 not to go in standby mode.

Comment: I hope I cleared it up. I want to run the script every time I log in.

Comment: Yes, better. Just for clarity do you always login when you come out of standby?

Comment: I do not have to login at boot. But Yes I always have to login when coming out of standby.